# Gamma spectroscopy - Do annihilation photons produce a backscatter peak?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, nuclear-physics, spectroscopy, data-analysis, gamma-rays

Below is a diagram of part of a structure which I find in a gamma spectrum taken from a hall in which a neutron source is undergoing spallation.

[image]

The structure which I'm interested in can be seen around 172-174KeV. I can't find suitable candidate isotopes which produce this structure. However, it could be explained as being a backscatter peak from 511KeV photons. This would make sense, and perhaps explain the strange shape (?).  My question is whether annihilation photons themselves can go on to produce a backscatter peak? If not, why not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 511-keV photons in the $^{22}Na$ spectrum are annihilation photons. They definitly have Compton interactions as seen in the diagram. The 1250-keV peak is a gamma in the daughter of the sodium positron decay.  It also has a Compton edge and a backscatter region. [image: ${22}Na$ gamma spectrum]

Answer (score 3):

Photons are photons.

If photons from one source experiences a certain kind of physics, then photons from other sources do too. So, short answer: **yes**.

And they can produce Compton edges as well.

Comment: As an example, take a look at a gamma spectrum from Na-22.